# Ionic transition not working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Hi I can't get the application to change page. Now I have had look at some example code here on stack but all of them doesn't use the 'app.login' but insteand just 'login'. I tried this but it caused a crash in the program.

My end goal is to transition to home from the login controller

**Controller**:

```
.controller('logInCtrl', function($scope) {
  //...
  $state.transitionTo("app.home");
  //...
})
```

**app.js**

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: you need to include `$state ` dependency on your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this `go()` function of `$state` to change page: `$state.go("app.home");` Plus do not forget to include `$state` dependency in your controller

```
.controller('logInCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
```